# popen returns -1 unexpectedly

Tags: c, linux, popen

I have a program that needs a file-list that is most easily generated by a script (that does a few configurable things besides generating the list)

In essence I do

```
fp = popen ("thescript", "r");
```

then

```
while (fgets (buf, 1024, fp))
```

and process the lines, and at the end:

```
rv = pclose (fp);
```

The (bash) script ends with `exit 0`. But when run "normally" the pclose call returns -1, ECHILD: No  child process.

What I like about Linux is that I can normally find such problems by running strace and see what really happens. Not this time: When running strace as a normal user the mount in the script fails, so the script does `exit 1` and `rv` reflects that. When I change that to exit 0 (when the mount fails!) the return value rv reflects that (`rv == 0`, gui does not print error message). When I run the whole thing as root while tracing, it works (`rv == 0`, no error message displayed).

I've written short test-program, and it all works as expected.

At first I wrote the code is proprietary. Decided it is simple enough to publish...  Here is the actual code that "malfunctions". The "get_str_param" will return the name of the script to run.

```
  files=popen(get_str_param("IMPORT_LIST"),"r");
  //printf ("calling  cmd for file list: %s\n", get_str_param("IMPORT_LIST"));
  while(fgets(buf, 1024, files)) {
    if((p=strstr(buf,".apl"))) {
      *p=0;
      if(strstr(buf," ")) continue; // ignore files with spaces

      fl_add_browser_line(fd_import->applications,buf);
    }
  }
  rv = pclose(files); 
  if (rv) {
    printf ("Can't read file list! rv=%d\n", rv);
```

The "fl_add_browser_line" is from the "xforms" library.

So... what could possibly cause an ECHILD, only when NOT tracing the program with strace?

Comment: If you can't produce a [MCVE] demonstrating the problem, and can't provide the code that actually has the problem, what precisely are you expecting us to do here? Psychically debug the code we're not allowed to see?

Comment: Does the program have its own `SIGCHLD` handler? `pclose()` has to use `waitpid()` to get the exit status of the child process. If something else in the program has already captured the exit status, or declared this as `SIG_IGN`, then there won't be anything for `pclose()` to retrieve.

Comment: `strace` might also be changing the timing of signal handling, causing this heisenbug.

Comment: Barmar: You go through to the next round. (In Dutch: "you continue for the washing machine")
You answered the question: "what could possible cause ..." with probably the correct answer:  "a SIGCHLD handler". Thanks! 
I'm off googling for a solution to have the SIGCHLD temporarily disabled.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You need to improve your psychic abilities if you want to get to 400K rep. :)

Comment: @barmar You were right. That fixes it. Would it be good form for me to add an answer, or do you want to get the credit for writing it?
I added oldchildhandler=signal (SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
before my popen and
signal (SIGCHLD, oldchildhandler); after, and that fixes it.

Comment: Should the title of the question be "pclose returns -1 unexpectedly"?

Answer (score 2):

It's not shown in the code excerpt that was posted, but apparently some other part of the program establishes a `SIGCHLD` handler. This will interfere with functions like `pclose()` and `system()`. The [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pclose) says:

> The `pclose()` function waits for the associated process to terminate and returns the exit status of the command as returned by `wait4(2)`.

If there's another `SIGCHLD` handler, and it calls `wait()`, then when `pclose()` tries to get the exit status itself the child will be gone, and it will get `ECHILD`.

You need to disable this handler while running the function that uses `popen()` and `pclose()`. Or write your own code that runs the child process and works in conjunction with the rest of your code that deals with forking.

You need to be careful about setting `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL)` around this code. If some other child process exits during this period, I don't think your regular handler will be notified when you re-establish the handler. I think you can deal with this by calling the regular handler explicitly after adding the handler back; when it calls `wait()` it will pick up any outstanding terminated processes.

Comment: Adding 
  old = signal (SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
before, and 
  signal (SIGCHILD, old); 
after the popen .. pclose section fixes the problem. I think it will even not interfere if another child exits in the intervening time: the pclose will wait for a specific pid, so other exiting children will be reaped by the signal handler, eventually.

Comment: I just added something about that. If another process exits, you'll never get a SIGCHLD for them, so there might not be an "eventually". You need to call `oldchildhandler` explicitly to make it check for an exited process.